# Parameter inside identifier

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to write a add query that will change depending on the parameter. I have several queries:

LastK1StatDate
LastK2StatDate
.
.
LastK15StatDate
LastK16StatDate

My criteria should change depending on the value entered for the parameter "qryKioskNum" when the query is run.

Currently my criteria is this:

```
>Max("[LastK" & [qryKioskNum] & "StatDate]![K" & [qryKioskNum] & "LastDate]")
```

qryKioskNum is type Short Text

It keeps giving me the error "The expression is typed incorrectly, or is too complex to be evaluated."

Here is the complete SQL statement for this query:

```
PARAMETERS qryKioskNum Short;  
INSERT INTO K1DispRejStat ( K1StatDate, K1BillCount1, K1BillCount2, 
K1BillCount3, K1BillCount4, K1BillCount5, K1BillCount6, K1BillRej1, 
K1BillRej2, K1BillRej3, K1BillRej4, K1BillRej5, K1BillRej6 )  
SELECT DateValue([responseFrames]![dispDateTime]) AS [Date], 
Sum(responseFrames.billCount1) AS SumOfbillCount1, 
Sum(responseFrames.billCount2) AS SumOfbillCount2, 
Sum(responseFrames.billCount3) AS SumOfbillCount3, 
Sum(responseFrames.billCount4) AS SumOfbillCount4, 
Sum(responseFrames.billCount5) AS SumOfbillCount5, 
Sum(responseFrames.billCount6) AS SumOfbillCount6, 
Sum(responseFrames.BillRej1) AS SumOfBillRej1, Sum(responseFrames.BillRej2) 
AS SumOfBillRej2, Sum(responseFrames.BillRej3) AS SumOfBillRej3, 
Sum(responseFrames.BillRej4) AS SumOfBillRej4, Sum(responseFrames.billRej5) 
AS SumOfbillRej5, Sum(responseFrames.billRej6) AS SumOfbillRej6  
FROM responseFrames, LastK1StatDate  
WHERE (((responseFrames.kioskID)="K1"))
GROUP BY DateValue([responseFrames]![dispDateTime])
HAVING (((DateValue([responseFrames]![dispDateTime]))>Max("[LastK" & 
[qryKioskNum] & "StatDate]![K1LastDate]")))
ORDER BY DateValue([responseFrames]![dispDateTime]);
```

*currently everything is set to "K1" but I would like all reference to K1 to be dynamic*

I think it is just a syntax issue but can't find how exactly this should be typed out.

Any help is great. Thanks!

*edited for clarity

Comment: add tempTxt = "[LastK" & [qryKioskNum] & "StatDate]![K1LastDate]"  and then msgbox(tempTxt), and then Max(tempTxt).  Tell us what you see.  What do you expect to get?  How does KDispRejStat fit into this? Or is it just spurious information?

Comment: Where am I adding all of this? Should this all go in the criteria?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in query object or build SQL in VBA? Post the entire SQL. Where is the value of qryKioskNum coming from? You have 16 query objects and you want to dynamically select which is referenced in another query object? I don't think that is possible.

Comment: I added quite a bit to clarify my exact question. I also included the SQL statement that you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In msaccess, create a PassThru query (because it retains the multi-line nice format).

Create // QueryDesign // Close // rightClick // SQLSpecific // PassThru

Paste in the following sql.

```
INSERT INTO kxxdisprejstat

            (kxxstatdate,
             kxxbillcount1,
             kxxbillcount2,
             kxxbillcount3,
             kxxbillcount4,
             kxxbillcount5,
             kxxbillcount6,
             kxxbillrej1,
             kxxbillrej2,
             kxxbillrej3,
             kxxbillrej4,
             kxxbillrej5,
             kxxbillrej6)

SELECT Datevalue([responseframes] ! [dispdatetime]) AS [Date],
       SUM(responseframes.billcount1)               AS SumOfbillCount1,
       SUM(responseframes.billcount2)               AS SumOfbillCount2,
       SUM(responseframes.billcount3)               AS SumOfbillCount3,
       SUM(responseframes.billcount4)               AS SumOfbillCount4,
       SUM(responseframes.billcount5)               AS SumOfbillCount5,
       SUM(responseframes.billcount6)               AS SumOfbillCount6,
       SUM(responseframes.billrej1)                 AS SumOfBillRej1,
       SUM(responseframes.billrej2)                 AS SumOfBillRej2,
       SUM(responseframes.billrej3)                 AS SumOfBillRej3,
       SUM(responseframes.billrej4)                 AS SumOfBillRej4,
       SUM(responseframes.billrej5)                 AS SumOfbillRej5,
       SUM(responseframes.billrej6)                 AS SumOfbillRej6

FROM   responseframes,
       lastkxxstatdate

WHERE  (( ( responseframes.kioskid ) = "kxx" ))

GROUP  BY Datevalue([responseframes] ! [dispdatetime])

HAVING (( ( Datevalue([responseframes] ! [dispdatetime]) ) 
           > Max([lastkxxstatdate]![kxxlastdate]) ))

ORDER  BY Datevalue([responseframes] ! [dispdatetime]);
```

Name it  kxxInsert   (or some such, using kxx to say that it is generalized).

Then add this to the program

```
Sub getKxx()
    Dim qrykiosknum As Integer  ' temp here to have something
    qrykiosknum = 3             ' temp here for an example

    Dim kxxSQL As String, strSQL As String
    kxxSQL = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("kxxInsert").SQL
    strSQL = Replace(kxxSQL, "kxx", "k" & qrykiosknum)
    'MsgBox (strSQL)  ' it is too big to see all of it
    Debug.Print strSQL

    ' then run strSQL


End Sub
```

Having dynamic tablename in MSAccess or MSSQLServer is possible when the Replace is done before executing the SQL.

Comment: This worked!

Although I had to remove the double quotes in the Max function under the Having section.

Comment: @jawohl I just fixed my copy also.  Glad you like it

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can make this work by using a query with a parameter. You are much better off using VBA. Use `InputBox` to get the variable portion of the query and `DoCmd.RunSQL` to run the query.